# With what shared objects are the debug symbols in a debug deb package assocciated with?

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I am trying to find debug symbols that are associated with various shared objects shipped under the Ubuntu 22.04 distro.

For example, let's consider the amd64 deb package: `libssl3` (version 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) which ships a number of stripped shared objects. One of them is `libcrypto.so.3`. My objective is to find out debug symbols for this ELF binary.

So I downloaded the debug symbols deb package - libssl3-dbgsym from Ubuntu launchpad ([Link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/kinetic/+package/libssl3-dbgsym)) and extract it. What I get is the following files:

```
.
├── .build-id
│   ├── 03
│   │   └── 29a35e5964f90f62f114339b04d01fdd279556.debug
│   ├── 1a
│   │   └── eb4e8099c7be4e1f6d3a19f67f984b7f8c84f7.debug
│   ├── 4c
│   │   └── 87efff7047c22be230cee0e46e02d5381176e4.debug
│   ├── 58
│   │   └── 379515d1cca66570c1f35281cea7801b09123b.debug
│   ├── 64
│   │   └── 6eb686ac2bdfec84a935d8e87aee7b31003764.debug
│   └── 76
│       └── 600b49bcd7f52abe72e54bca385de322f175a2.debug
└── .dwz
    └── x86_64-linux-gnu
        ├── libssl3.debug
```

What ELF binaries do these debug files under `.build-id` correspond to? Why aren't there any debug symbols that correspond to, say `libcrypto.so.3` or `libssl.so.3`?

I did read that a lot of these debug packages are automatically generated and might be empty. However, it will be helpful if I can make sense of what these `*.debug` files are and how to use these symbols if at all they can be used for the various shared objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug files correspond to the binary with a matching build id. To find a build id, use `eu-readelf` (in the `elfutils` package); for example, on my system,

```
$ eu-readelf -n /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1

Note section [ 1] '.note.gnu.build-id' of 36 bytes at offset 0x238:
  Owner          Data size  Type
  GNU                   20  GNU_BUILD_ID
    Build ID: 0c53740d5c74564b10ffdc9b15aa30961bd7221d
```

The first two hex digits of the build id map to a directory under `.build-id`, the rest to a specific `.debug` file.